# cudaMemcpy - Receive error : cudaErrorInvalidValue 11

Tags: cuda, nvcc

Here is my code :

```
unsigned char *d_eCB[9];
unsigned char eCB[9] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
err = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_eCB,9*sizeof(unsigned char));
err = cudaMemcpy(d_eCB, eCB, 9*sizeof(unsigned char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

The error occurs on the following line :

```
err = cudaMemcpy(d_eCB, eCB, 9*sizeof(unsigned char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

The error is as follows : cudaErrorInvalidValue 11

Comment: Why `unsigned char *d_eCB[9];` ?

Comment: Just change `unsigned char *d_eCB[9];` to `unsigned char *d_eCB;`

Comment: Oh, thank you so much.  That was IT!

Comment: Somebody please add an answer to this question. It is one thing to have a "spot my elementary mistake" question, it is quite another to have an *unanswered* "spot my elementary mistake" question

Answer (score 3):

I changed

```
unsigned char *d_eCB[9];
```

to

```
unsigned char *d_eCB;
```

Thank you.